# ignore curly brackets in regex expression

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, replace

I am trying to build an application which does the following :

1) write some text in a richtextbox

---

2) when user clicks a button, the app will replace the text with another text in {} braces.

what I want is that the next time, the regex searches for any text it should exclude those which are present in {}.

**for eg :**

my world is good world and a happy world and will be a better world for everyone.

**first pass - change word "world"**

my {world|happy place|home} is good {world|happy place|home} and a happy {world|happy place|home} and will be a better {world|happy place|home} for everyone.

**second pass - change word "happy"**

in this pass I want the regex to ignore all instances which are surrounded by {}. notice word happy comes in {world|happy place|home}, but it should not be touched.

now could anyone please help me with building this regex?

**In simple terms I want to include the word and exclude everything that falls between {}. Also please note that word can be a string.**

for eg : sometimes I might want to replace the string "happy place".

any other logic other than regex can also help.

my code is :

```
Dim fil2 As New StreamReader("new2.txt")

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim start2 As Integer = 0
    Dim rgx As Regex

    Dim rpl As String = RichTextBox1.Text

    Do While fil2.Peek > -1
        Dim StringToCheck As String = fil2.ReadLine()
        Dim prev As String = StringToCheck.Split("|")(0).Trim()

        If (StringToCheck.Split("|")(0).Split(" ").Count >= 2) Then
            Try
                rgx = New Regex("(?<=(^|})[^{]*)" & prev & "(?=[^}]*($|{))")
                Dim z As Integer = 0

                rpl = rgx.Replace(rpl, "{" & StringToCheck & "}")


            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If


    Loop

    fil2.Close()

    rpl = rpl.Replace("{?  ?|?  ?|? ! ?}", " ")
    RichTextBox1.Text = rpl
    MsgBox("done")
```

Comment: what your final string should be?

Comment: it depends on how many words there are in the list to be replaced. it is dynamic. but to give a general layout, there should not be any nested {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
"(?<=(^|})[^{]*)happy(?=[^}]*($|{))"
```

Comment: hey petar thanks for the answer, i will check it but tell me do you know vb.net? I ask just to find out whether we can replace happy wih a string variable like "(?<=(^|})[^{]*)" & strvar & "(?=[^}]*($|{))"

Comment: also there seems to be a problem. I want to change only words - individual words. With current replace method this is happening :                                                                      so in softwares is getting replaced by {so|why|so what} etc. Any way to avoid this ?

Comment: @user1045010 just use word boundaries additionally to the searched word, like this `\bhappy\b` and of course the other stuff from Petars answer.

Comment: hey stema and petar - i forgot to say thanks. after 2 days iam able to correctly use it. I tried searching for adding rep but couldn't find it. So thanks for the help. god bless u and warm regards :)